# How to prevent accessing particular database in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, software-design

I'm working on a Windows application. When I give this software to the client it is necessary to give database also? I want to lock the database of SQL Server on his computer so that he can not open that database or copy or view its schema or anything by which he can access that database.

When he tries to access that, it must ask for a password. So, what is the solution for the above?

Answer (score 0):

1. SQL Server databases cannot be password-protected - they're not just files that get opened (like dBase or SQLite)
2. "normal" access control is handled via permissions and users - you can define who can see what, modify what, delete what
3. This does not however prevent a system admin from looking at your database schema and contents; there's really no way to prevent this, a sysadmin can also just copy the `.mdf` file to another server and attach it there and circumvent all your "security"
4. if you really must hide all of this, don't deliver a database - hide the database in your own company and provide a web-service based interface to the customer who can then call those web services to do his work - then the schema and data is under your control, but also: the customer's data is no longer under *his* control so he might not like that.....